# Can we pass array data in redirect function of Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

How do you pass array data with a redirect function in Codeigniter?

I've passed an array but in URL print base url/controller/Array.
in My Controller.

```
 function getDefaultValue()
 {
     $dataArr=stateData();
     /*$dataArr array */ 
     redirect('home/'$dataArr);

 }
```

Comment: No, you can use flashdata (storage in cookies/session/database) that last "one" reload.

Answer (score 2):

As of my comment, here is an example:

```
function getDefaultValue()
{
    $dataArr=stateData();
    /*$dataArr array */ 
    $this->session->set_flashdata('my_super_array', $dataArr);
    redirect('home/'$dataArr);
}
```

and retrieve data as following

```
$this->session->flashdata('my_super_array');
```

You can find more [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Set your data in session and access that session on another page.

```
$dataArr=stateData();
$this->session->set_userdata("dataArr",$dataArr);
$this->session->userdata("dataArr");
```

after your work complition unset that session key

```
$this->session->unset_userdata("dataArr");
```